# Mistmatch between Socrata JSON and CSV metadata

Tags: socrata

There is a mismatch between the columns defined in the JSON metadata and the CSV data for a dataset.

For example, the metadata listing shows the columns - name, address1, address2, city, ...

https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/api/views/ecam-8hbr.json

But the CSV listing has address1, address2, category, city, ...

https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/ecam-8hbr.csv?$limit=2&$offset=0

Answer (score 0):

It's not that they don't match, the fields are just presented in different orders.

The CSV lists the columns in alphabetical order:

```
"address1","address2","category",...,"zip"
```

Whereas the JSON metadata lists the fields in the same order that *the dataset was originally defined* (when data was first uploaded). Look at the [dataset in the Web UI](https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/Health-and-Human-Services/Food-Inspection/5pue-gfbe), the fields are in the same order as the JSON metadata. *Note the location column in the dataset is broken out into component columns in the export*.

```
"name","address1",...,"location","location_city","location_address","location_zip","location_state"
```

Both representations have the same 34 standard fields. The JSON metadata includes an additional 4 fields that appear to be computed and related to other datasets, so not included in the CSV export.

Comment: And the new search integration - http://geodesystems.com/repository/search/textform?provider=socrata